# Pagination in Drupal 6 search results

Tags: search, multi-sites, paging

I am using the [Multisite Search](http://drupal.org/project/multisite_search) module and have added some custom behaviour to it.
What I did was basically do another check in the multisite_search_search function and stopped
several nodes from reaching the $result variable. This stopped them from displaying.

My problem is that this causes the paging to fail. I know the paging is done in the do_search function, before I remove certain results from being displayed. This causes the result page to display varying amounts of results per page, depending on how many I took out from that particular page.

Is there a way I can fix this? Redo the pagination in the search function? Maybe not adding node to $result is not enough or should I have gone differently about it?